# Zsh read output of command into array splitting on newline

Tags: zsh

I have a command that outputs a bunch of stuff e.g. running `mycmd` will give:

```
foobar
derp derp
like so
etc
```

Some of these lines will have spaces in them.

How do I read these into an array in zsh such that `${arr[1]}` gives `foobar`, `${arr[2]}` gives `derp derp` etc.

I have tried something like but it seems to split the array on chars not newlines.

```
IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -r arr <<< "$(mycmd)"
```

i.e. `${arr[1]}` gives `f` when it should give `foobar`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Okay its actually very simple:

```
IFS=$'\n' arr=($(mycmd))
```

Comment: This command will affect the IFS of the following commands. Is there a way to prevent it?

Comment: You can just set it back to its default afterward `IFS=$' \t\n'`

Comment: Thanks. I got another approach, which is `arr=(${(f)"$(mycmd)"})` or in two steps `tmp=$(mycmd)`, `arr=(${(f)tmp})`

Comment: @LiuSha That's not work for me. I want create a array for output of `ps -aux | grep python`, your suggestion failed.

Comment: @roachsinai I have no idea. did you try other simpler commands like `ls`? The double quote is essential. Maybe there is some zsh option controlling this.

Comment: @doraemon the oneline for `arr=(${(f)"$(mycmd)"})` works for me, thank you.  One thing I found with that is that `mycmd` had to be the actual command and not the variable output stored as `$mycmd`.  I am curious about the breakdown of what each part does.  Thank you.

Comment: @keith-e-truesdell: Working from the inside out: `$(mycmd)` - Use a "command substitution", which expands to the output of `mycmd`. `"..."` - Double-quote the command substitution, which prevents its output from being split into words on whitespace, preserving any extra spaces. `${(f)...}` - Apply the "parameter expansion flag" `f` to the command substitution, splitting its output into words using newline (`\n`) as the separator. `arr=(...)` - Set an array parameter `arr`, using the separated output lines as the elements of the array. See `man zshexpn` for more details.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly why the `read` usage in the original question didn't work. It's possibly related to mixing `<<<` and `$()`. Or maybe the user just had a messed up shell session. Or maybe it was a bug in an older version of Zsh.

In any case, it has nothing to do with the behavior of the `read` builtin, and the original proposal was very close to correct. The only problem was using `<<< $(...)` instead of a plain pipe, which *should* just be a stylistic goof (rather than an error).

The following works perfectly fine in Zsh 5.8.1 and 5.9:

```
function mycmd {
  print foobar
  print derp derp
  print like so
  print etc
}

typeset -a lines
mycmd | IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' -A lines

echo ${(F)lines}
```

You should see:

```
foobar
derp derp
like so
etc
```

I prefer this style, instead of `( $(...) )`. Not requiring a subshell is useful in many cases, and the quoting/escaping situation is a lot simpler.

Note that `-d ''` is required to prevent `read` from terminating at the first newline.

You can wrap this up in a function easily:

```
function read-lines {
    if (( $# != 1 )); then
        print -u2 'Exactly 1 argument is required.'
        return 2
    fi

    local array="${1:-}"
    read -r -d '' "$array"
}
```

Comment: There is a gotcha, because now echo $#lines unexpectedly prints 5, and ${lines[5]-unset} expands to blank instead of unset. why does the array have a fifth blank element? it's because the final newline in the input, when there is one, is treated as a field *separator*, not a record *terminator*, when IFS=$'\n'. how you handle this is up to you, but it can be a real landmine for subsequent iteration.